# Intersection of two non-linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-system

Graphically it is clear that $$1 + 2e^{{(x-y)}^2}(x-y) = 0$$ $$e^{{(x-y)}^2} - y = 0$$ has a unique solution, but how do I solve this analytically? If this is not possible, then what would be an appropriate technique to try and estimate the answer.

Comment: Substitute $y=e^{(x-y)^2}$ into  the first equation and you're pretty much done...

Comment: That doesn't remove any variables though so you still can't find a single solution.

Comment: It is a point, this is clear if you graph it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $t = (x-y)^2$, the equations say

$$ \eqalign{1 \pm 2 e^{t} \sqrt{t} &= 0\cr
             y &= e^{t}\cr}$$
From the first equation, 
   $$ 1/2 = 2 t e^{2t} $$
so $2t$ must be one of the branches of $W(1/2)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  If you're interested in real solutions, there is only one real branch.
Moreover we must have $x-y < 0$ in the first equation so $x - y = -\sqrt{t}$.  Thus
$$ \eqalign{y &= e^t = e^{W(1/2)/2} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 W(1/2)}}\cr
            x &= y - \sqrt{t} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 W(1/2)}} - \sqrt{W(1/2)/2}\cr}$$

Comment: May I ask, how were you able to get $ 1/2 = 2 t e^{2t} $ from the first equation?

Comment: Ah, let me answer my own question: 
$$1 - 2{e^t}\sqrt{t} = 0$$
$$1 = 2{e^t}\sqrt{t}$$
$$(1)^2 = (2{e^t}\sqrt{t})^2$$
$$1 = 4{e^{2t}}{t}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} = 2{e^{2t}}{t}$$